# Refering global values from JSON in the table footer

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I'm using the `Table` in the `Jasper Reports`. I've defined the `subDataset`, over which the Table iterates:

```
<subDataset name="Dataset1"
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JSON"/>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[result.details]]>
    </queryString>
....
```

Now I need to refer a field from the structure other then result.details:

```
    <field name="totalTax" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="result.Description" value="result.cantonal.cantonalTax.totalTax"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[result.description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
```

The problem is, that I get `'null'` in the field, which results from, I suppose, that Jasper resolves the field relative to the `result.details`. How to add JSON field that would be addressed from globally?

Comment: AFIK as long as you are in the context of the subDataset you do not have access to it (it's not part of the subDataset). A solution could be to send this data as a parameter to the subDataset.

Comment: You could consider switching to JSONQL, see https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html#jsonqldatasource

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks, it was the solution. Add parameter to the dataset, and then, in the Table->Dataset->Parameters I could choose the mapped field from the main dataset.